# Are node.js clusters different instances entirely?

Tags: node.js, web, websocket, socket.io

I have a simple websocket multiplayer game using socket.io.

I am using clusters right now and for each new worker I instantiate a new gameServer object and do gameServer.start();

```js
GameServer.prototype.start = function () {  
    var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var server = require('http').Server(app);

    /** INIT PORT CONNECTION **/
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/web/index.html');
    });
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/web'));
    server.listen(2000); //port number for listening
    console.log('Started Server!');
```

Each gameServer object includes its own PLAYER_LIST, APPLE_LIST, etc.

Does that mean that each worker will have different data? Will that mean that if a user connects to one worker it might not have the complete data set and be on a completely DIFFERENT server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes those are different instances. Consider using a Redis store or something similar to share data between the instances.

Redis is nice because it is fast and works on a simple put and get basis where you can put and object and read an object pretty easily

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have different data. Try to use [socket.io-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-redis) package for sync your instances through Redis.

Comment: Do i have to convert my gameServer instances into redis before I can start?

Comment: I don't quite understand it yet. I don't understand what an adapter is or why I need rooms (what are rooms?) If I want to sync all the server instances, is it just one simple command?